# PHPDoc GraphViz error unable to fork and dot command not found

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04, graphviz, phpdoc

I have found a few related questions here but they all seem to be solved by installing a missing graphiz. In my case it is certainly installed and in the path.

The error from PHPDoc is:

```
 Execute transformation using writer "Graph"
 PHP Warning:  exec(): Unable to fork [dot -V 2>&1] in     /usr/share/php/phpDocumentor/src/phpDocumentor/Plugin/Graphs/Writer/Graph.     php on line 254
 PHP Stack trace:
 PHP   1. {main}() /usr/bin/phpdoc:0
 PHP   2. phpDocumentor\Application->run() /usr/bin/phpdoc:24
 PHP   3. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /usr/share/php/phpDocumentor/src/phpDocumentor/Application.php:183
 PHP   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() /usr/share/php/phpDocumentor/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126
 PHP   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() /usr/share/php/phpDocumentor/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:195
 PHP   6. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() /usr/share/php/phpDocumentor/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:874
 PHP   7. phpDocumentor\Command\Project\RunCommand->execute() /usr/share/php/phpDocumentor/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:253
 PHP   8. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() /usr/share/php/phpDocumentor/src/phpDocumentor/Command/Project/RunCommand.php:275
 PHP   9. phpDocumentor\Transformer\Command\Project\TransformCommand->execute() /usr/share/php/phpDocumentor/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:253
 PHP  10. phpDocumentor\Console\Output\Output->writeTimedLog() /usr/share/php/phpDocumentor/src/phpDocumentor/Transformer/Command/Project/TransformCommand.php:206
 PHP  11. call_user_func_array:{/usr/share/php/phpDocumentor/src/phpDocumentor/Console/Output/Output.php:59}() /usr/share/php/phpDocumentor/src/phpDocumentor/Console/Output/Output.php:59
 PHP  12. phpDocumentor\Transformer\Transformer->execute() /usr/share/php/phpDocumentor/src/phpDocumentor/Console/Output/Output.php:59
 PHP  13. phpDocumentor\Transformer\Transformer->transformProject() /usr/share/php/phpDocumentor/src/phpDocumentor/Transformer/Transformer.php:141
 PHP  14. phpDocumentor\Transformer\Transformer->applyTransformationToProject() /usr/share/php/phpDocumentor/src/phpDocumentor/Transformer/Transformer.php:275
 PHP  15. phpDocumentor\Plugin\Graphs\Writer\Graph->transform() /usr/share/php/phpDocumentor/src/phpDocumentor/Transformer/Transformer.php:312
 PHP  16. phpDocumentor\Plugin\Graphs\Writer\Graph->processClass() /usr/share/php/phpDocumentor/src/phpDocumentor/Plugin/Graphs/Writer/Graph.php:58
 PHP  17. phpDocumentor\Plugin\Graphs\Writer\Graph->checkIfGraphVizIsInstalled() /usr/share/php/phpDocumentor/src/phpDocumentor/Plugin/Graphs/Writer/Graph.php:72
 PHP  18. exec() /usr/share/php/phpDocumentor/src/phpDocumentor/Plugin/Graphs/Writer/Graph.php:254
 Unable to find the `dot` command of the GraphViz package. Is GraphViz correctly installed and present in your path?  32.682s
```

I know graphiz is installed and present in my path because:

**~$ dot -v**

```
 dot - graphviz version 2.36.0 (20140111.2315)
 libdir = "/usr/lib/graphviz"
 Activated plugin library: libgvplugin_dot_layout.so.6
 Using layout: dot:dot_layout
 Activated plugin library: libgvplugin_core.so.6
 Using render: dot:core
 Using device: dot:dot:core
 The plugin configuration file:
 /usr/lib/graphviz/config6
 was successfully loaded.
 render :  cairo dot fig gd map pic pov ps svg tk vml vrml xdot
 layout :  circo dot fdp neato nop nop1 nop2 osage patchwork sfdp        twopi
 textlayout :  textlayout
 device :  canon cmap cmapx cmapx_np dot eps fig gd gd2 gif gv imap imap_np ismap jpe jpeg jpg pdf pic plain plain-ext png pov ps ps2 svg svgz tk vml vmlz vrml wbmp x11 xdot xdot1.2 xdot1.4 xlib
 loadimage  :  (lib) eps gd gd2 gif jpe jpeg jpg png ps svg xbm
```

Additionally, if I run phpdoc as sudo it works just fine. The above error is only appearing when I run PHPDoc as a user. To get it to work with my particular situation I need it to work as user however.

I can't help but think that in this particular case the issue is more related to "unable to fork" than "unable to find the dot command". But not sure how to address that particular issue.

Some other perhaps helpful information:

```
 Ubuntu 14.04
 PHP 5.5.33
 phpDocumentor version 2.8.5

                total    used   free    shared    buffers   cached
 Mem:           992      512    479     9         55        319
```